# How To Set New Cell Value With LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method that currently removes rows that are null across all specified columns that match a sequence of regexes.

Instead of removing these rows, I'd like to change the value they have at the column flag index to 1.

How can I do this?

```
        public void FlagRowsWithNulls(string theColumnMatchString, string theColumnExceptString, string theColumnFlagString)
        {
            var rx = new Regex(theColumnMatchString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var rx2 = new Regex(theColumnExceptString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            var columnCheckIndices = (from c in ColumnNames
                where rx.IsMatch(c)
                where !rx2.IsMatch(c)
                select LookupColumnIndexForIdentifier(c)).ToList();

            var columnFlagIndex = LookupColumnIndexForIdentifier(theColumnFlagString);

            Data.RemoveAll(l => columnCheckIndices.All(i => l[i] == ""));
        }
```

Comment: FYI, `columnFlagIndex` (and therefore `theColumnFlagString`) appears to be unused.

Comment: What type is `Data`?

Comment: Thanks @RufusL. That is intentional. I'd like to use that yet unused variable to accomplish the task as it relates to the question asked.

Comment: Data is a List<List<string>>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Data.RemoveAll(l => columnCheckIndices.All(i => l[i] == ""));
```

Do something like this?

```
foreach(var index in columnCheckIndices.Where(i => l[i] == ""))
{
    Data[columnFlagIndex] = 1;
}
```

I note your "with LINQ" in the title, and in case you're wondering why I'm using a `foreach` instead of some kind of fancy lambda-based approach, I want to point out that removing or changing things is antithetical to the mindset behind LINQ. You're typically better off using imperative programming (loops, etc.) for state changes, and using functional programming (LINQ) for transforming data. This is called Command/Query Separation. See [Eric Lippert's post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach) describing why LINQ didn't include a `ForEach` method, for more info.

Comment: That's sort of closer. However, all the specified columns of columnCheckIndices still need to be empty for a given row to qualify, not any given one like you have it. Also, you need to give data two elements, since it's a List<List<string>>, in order to identify which row and column to set to "1". If you can tell me how to write the foreach that incorporates the row indices as well as the condition that they all are empty (e.g. .All), then that would be all I need to set the precise values in Data.

Comment: @MarkMcGown: You don't provide nearly enough data in your sample code for me to guess at the types and meanings of what you have there, or to understand what you mean by your above comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

        public void FlagEmptyColumns(string theColumnMatchString, string theColumnExceptString, string theColumnFlagString)
        {
            var rx = new Regex(theColumnMatchString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var rx2 = new Regex(theColumnExceptString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            var columnCheckIndices = (from c in ColumnNames
                where rx.IsMatch(c)
                where !rx2.IsMatch(c)
                select LookupColumnIndexForIdentifier(c)).ToList();

            var columnFlagIndex = LookupColumnIndexForIdentifier(theColumnFlagString);

            foreach (var l in Data)
            {
                if (columnCheckIndices.All(i => l[i] == ""))
                {
                   l[columnFlagIndex] = "1";
                }
            }
        }
```